# Playing multiple sounds in Unity5

Tags: c#, unity, audio

I have multiple `AudioClip`s that I have attached to a `GameObject` and I'm trying to play them when certain conditions are met.  Each clip is in an array and I have each array item attached to a variable.  I'm also getting the `GameObject`'s `Audio Source`.  My problem is, I can't get the clips to actually play, how do I get them to do so?

**C#**

```
private Rigidbody playerCar;
private AudioSource engine;
public AudioClip[] carSounds = new AudioClip[3];
AudioClip accelerate;
AudioClip toppedOut;
AudioClip idle;
private bool accelerating;
private bool idling;
private bool maxed;

void Start(){
    playerCar = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    engine = playerCar.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    carSounds = playerCar.GetComponents<AudioClip>();
    idle = carSounds[0];
    accelerate = carSounds[1];
    toppedOut = carSounds[2];
    idling = true;
}

void Update(){
    if(idling){
        engine.PlayOneShot(idle);
        accelerating = false;
        maxed = false;
    }
}
```

**Editor**

[image]

For further clarification, here is the exact error Unity is giving me.

`ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'AudioClip' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponents[AudioClip] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineGameObjectBindings.gen.cs:100)
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponents[AudioClip] () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineComponentBindings.gen.cs:183)
MoveCar.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MoveCar.cs:28)`

Line 28 is `carSounds = playerCar.GetComponents<AudioClip>();`

Comment: Your code looks okay. In the editor, have you clicked and dragged your AudioClips into the carSounds array?

Comment: @Chris I have, I'll add a screenshot to the question

Comment: Just to rule out there isn't an issue with `PlayOneShot`, could you try `engine.clip = idle; engine.Play();`? Does this play the clip? Is the "Mute Audio" button below the Game tab is pressed? Does your computer play other sounds okay? Have you tried closing and re-opening Unity? Restarted your computer?

Comment: I've tried setting the clip the way you mention.  The computer has no issues playing other sounds, I'm even able to hear it when I just play the clip from the editor.  I haven't tried restarting Unity though, I'll give that a shot.  I also updated the question with more details.

Comment: Ah, thanks for posting the error. Error messages help solve things. `GetComponents` returns `Component[]` I believe, which is not `AudioClip[]`. Let me write up an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37202/discussion-between-chris-and-robert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big edit:

From chatting and working with Robert on this, to resolve this issue, the solution seems to be:

1. Remove the `carSounds = playerCar.GetComponents<AudioClip>();` line because `GetComponents<AudioClip>()` will always return a null array because AudioClips aren't components that can be added to GameObjects. This was overwriting the AudioClips that had already been assigned in the Inspector tab.
2. [PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) just doesn't seem to work. Perhaps an issue with Unity?
3. Add in extra code to assign engine's AudioClip and tell it to Play.

Working code:

```
if (idling) {
    engine.loop = true;
    engine.clip = carSounds[0];
    if (!engine.isPlaying) {
        engine.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error saying that I can't implicitly convert the `AudioClip` type to a `Component`.  Here's the exact wording.  `Assets/Scripts/MoveCar.cs(28,21): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.AudioClip[]' to `UnityEngine.Component[]'`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to cast in `(AudioClip)`. I've updated the `for` loop now.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So, why would carSounds be returning as Components if I told them to return as AudioClips?

Comment: I'm actually getting the same error though.

Comment: @Chris If you call `PlayOneShot` before previous play is finished, it cuts previous one immediately and starts new one. So, if you call it on `Update()`, you cannot hear anything, because it start audio clip over and over again at every frame.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN Ah right, that might've been part of the issue then, as it would have been looping. Good to know. Thanks.